# Access string as a file handle in C

Tags: c, unit-testing

I need to write unit tests in C for a function that operates on a file handle. I would like to include the contents of the test files directly into the unit test source. Thus my question: is it possible to define a string and access it as file handle in C?

Comment: See Ryan's answer and my comment. These are the correct way for POSIX, and may be standardized in C1x. If you need to support non-POSIX systems you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: POSIX will do just fine, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On linux, see `fmemopen` and `open_memstream`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fmemopen(void *buf, size_t size, const char *mode);

FILE *open_memstream(char ** ptr, size_t *sizeloc);
```

Comment: Replace `#define _GNU_SOURCE` with `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`. These are standard POSIX interfaces since 2008. `fmemopen`, not `open_memstream`, is the one you want.

Comment: That is pretty sweet, hadn't heard of that!

Answer (score 0):

If what you're testing is only reading (not seeking or writing, or doing fcntl and stuff) or only writing, then it is quite possible to realize this by using a pipe, and forking. I've never done this in windows, but I suppose it should be possible as both pipe and fork are POSIX.

You need to create a pipe first, then fork, and start writing your text into the pipe from the child (or the parent, and run the test in the child, I prefer to have to child to the writing though), and the read-fd of the pipe you pass to your code under test. The child should keep writing until it's finished (which might require multiple calls to write) or the pipe is closed. If your code under test is writing, the child should read until the pipe is closed (may have to call read more than once), as otherwise the tested code will block waiting for someone to read, or die on a broken pipe.

HTH.